# Error :Incompatible types: NUMERIC and STRING in Compute Expressions

Tags: dashboard, einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein

I have created a compute field named x of type text.I used ah field y in compute expression which is of numeric .Basically i want to output to be ***'y'+"some text"*** which would be used as dimension.But the Dataflow fails saying ***Incompatible types: NUMERIC and STRING*** .**How to achieve concatenation using compute fields ???**

Answer (score 0):

If you using a formula  then use

```
Text(Numeric_field_Name__C) + text_Field__c
```

If you are trying it in apex code and want to store result in text field then use

```
string.valueOf(Numeric_field_Name__C) + text_Field__c
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly refer the y field since its numeric and then the rest as your are using it before. 
y + "Sometext"